# Am I using correct approach? Find $variance(x^2 +1)$ of the following distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following distribution (this is just for a conceptual check, so I'm making it up right now).

```
x    p(x)
1     .3
2     .5
3     .2
```

Am I correct in this approach?
$var(a) = E[a^2] - (E[a])^2$

So...

let a = $x^2+1$
$E[a] = E[x^2 +1] = [(1^2+1)(.3)] + [(2^2+1)(.5)] + ...$

and

$E[a^2] = E[(x^2 +1)^2] = [((1)^2+1)^2(.3)] + [((2)^2+1)^2(.5)] + ...$

Is this how I use the $x^2+1$ in the variance formula?

Comment: That all looks good, yes. Since $x^2$ and $1$ are independent (or if you like, shifting a variable does not change its variance), you also get $var(x^2 + 1) = var(x^2) + var(1) = var(x^2)$. And adding a constant to a variable just adds the same constant to its expectation. So $E(x^2 + 1) = E(x^2) + 1$.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't think about that. So I can calculate $E[x^2]$ and THEN add 1?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to first observe that $$\operatorname{Var}[A+c] = \operatorname{Var}[A]$$ for any random variable $A$ for which the variance is finite, and for any constant (non-stochastic) $c$.  Then $$\operatorname{Var}[X^2 + 1] = \operatorname{Var}[X^2] = \operatorname{E}[X^4] - \operatorname{E}[X^2]^2.$$  We then can easily compute for appropriate values of $k$ $$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \sum_{x=1}^3 x^k \Pr[X = x].$$

---

For a proof of the above property of variance, note $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Var}[A+c] &= \operatorname{E}[(A+c - \operatorname{E}[A+c])^2] \\ &= \operatorname{E}[(A+c - (\operatorname{E}[A]+c))^2] \\ &= \operatorname{E}[(A - \operatorname{E}[A])^2] \\ &= \operatorname{Var}[A]. \end{align*}$$